Invalid app registration, see https://aka.ms/AppRegInfo for more information
I am creating an oath2 system where when people login with Microsoft I can see their Minecraft username. I've come very far until I've stumbled up on this error:
errorMessage: 'Invalid app registration, see https://aka.ms/AppRegInfo for more information'

This is the exact request I've used:
      const minecraftTokenResponse = await axios.post('https://api.minecraftservices.com/authentication/login_with_xbox', {
        "identityToken": `XBL3.0 x=${uhs};${xstsToken}`,
        "ensureLegacyEnabled" : true
    }, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    });

I have verified and checked, I am 100% sure that all the xsts tokens and uhs etc are good, everything works besides this request. Anyone able to help?
